# Debug Error R6010 abort() has been called -

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to write in a program to read in a arbitrary comma separated matrix and then print the matrix out to screen. My program is shown below. When ever I try to run the program, I get the error message 'Debug Error!... R6010 -abort() has been called' or something like that. I feel like it may be a problem with how the program is built as the same program below worked on a different compiler. I'm using visual studio 2013. I have very little experience with this software so answers in plain terms would be appreciated. Even when I start the program without debugging I still get this error.

```
//includes
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

//main programme begins here
int main() {
    //define vectors to read matrix into
    vector <vector<double>> Matrix;
    string aLine, element;

    //openfile
    ifstream InputMatrix("inputmatrix.txt");
    while (!InputMatrix.eof()) {
       getline(InputMatrix, aLine);
       size_t commapos = 0;
       vector <double> across;
       while (commapos != string::npos) {
          commapos = aLine.find(',', 0);
          string element = aLine.substr(0, commapos);
          aLine = aLine.substr(commapos + 1, aLine.length() - commapos - 1);
          across.push_back(stod(element));
          }
       Matrix.push_back(across);
   }
   InputMatrix.close(); //closes file


   //check file has read in correctly
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < Matrix.size(); i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < Matrix[i].size(); j++) {
        cout << Matrix[i][j] << ", ";
      }
      cout << "\n ";
   }



  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Don't do `while (!somefile.eof())`, it's almost always wrong. Instead do e.g. `while (std::getline(somefile, somestring))`.

Comment: As for your problem, run in a debugger to catch the abortion in action. Then you can locate where it happens in your code and hopefully see why it happens by examining the values of the involved variables.